# How to make cubes position so that they do not collide with each other in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cube prefab. I want to spawn a few and place them in rows and columns. So I added collider and rigidbody on the cube. Now the cubes position is not calculated properly and I want to position them after spawning but my approach is not working. I tried to position the cubes based on overlaps and repositioning them apart. But that seems not effecting or positioning cubes in right position, so after spawning, force is added and cubes are thrown apart.

My goal is to spawn and put cubes on top of each other stacked. Current problem is cubes are positioned overlapping while spawning.

code:

```
   //spawn
  //Vector3 offset = new Vector3(1.0f, 100f, 100f); 
    List<GameObject> cubes = new List<GameObject>();

    foreach (var item in cubesPrefabs)
    {
        var mBox = Instantiate(box, parent.transform);

        Transform cubeTransform = mBox.GetComponent<Transform>();

        // Get references to the cube's collider and rigidbody
        Collider cubeCollider = mBox.GetComponent<Collider>();
        Rigidbody cubeRigidbody = mBox.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Add the cube to the list
        cubes.Add(mBox);

        // Calculate the scale required to match the desired size in meters
        Vector3 scale = new Vector3(((float)item.cLength / cubeTransform.localScale.x) ,
                                     ((float)item.cHeight / cubeTransform.localScale.y),
                                     ((float)item.cWidth / cubeTransform.localScale.z) );

        // Set the scale of the cube to match the desired size in meters
        cubeTransform.localScale = scale;

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(item.cPosL, item.cPosH , item.cPosW );
        cubeTransform.localPosition = pos;

        Debug.Log("Look here. pos: " + pos.ToString() + " , scale: " + scale.ToString());
        // Check for collisions with all other cubes in the list
        for (int i = 0; i < cubes.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // Get references to the collider and rigidbody of the other cube
            Collider otherCollider = cubes[i].GetComponent<Collider>();
            Rigidbody otherRigidbody = cubes[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            // Check if the two colliders are overlapping
            if (cubeCollider.bounds.Intersects(otherCollider.bounds))
            {
                // Calculate the direction and distance to move the cubes apart
                Vector3 direction = (cubeTransform.position - cubes[i].transform.position).normalized;
                float distance = Mathf.Abs(cubeCollider.bounds.min.x - otherCollider.bounds.max.x);

                // Move the cubes apart along the calculated direction and distance
                cubeRigidbody.MovePosition(cubeTransform.position + direction * distance / 2.0f);
                otherRigidbody.MovePosition(cubes[i].transform.position - direction * distance / 2.0f);
            }
        }

    }
```

With or without repositioning:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create rows and columns, the simplest method would be to cache the position of the last box you placed, and then add the box size to that to get the next position.

E.g.

```
//Need the collider or mesh to get the bounds size
//Am using y to show the idea of stacking    
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(1,1,1);
float scaleY = item.meshRenderer.bounds.size.y; 


//Now lets say you have placed item 1 at pos, 
//and saved it's position into a new global variable lastPos. 
//For item 2 Position you would do something like this:
Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(lastPos.x, lastPos.y + (scaleY * 0.5f), lastPos.z);
```

I usually get the bounds size from the renderer, and divide it by 2. But you may want something different. So just play around with the amounts until you get the desired distances. And this of course can also be done with the x and the z at the same time.

Am at work so I can't properly write/test the code, but hopefully you get the idea. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Just change theirs `position` or `localPosition`. Don't use `MovePosition`, it will simulate physical effects and you should only use it in the `FixedUpdate` method (as well as other physical callbacks).

```
cubeTransform.position += direction * distance / 2.0f;
```